# Convert Row Resultset to Column SQLite

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, sqlite

I have a resultset like this from my query using SQLite

```
ID    description   value
1      name          john
2.     age            30
3.     location       kl
```

I want to convert the resultset to columns like this

```
name     age      location
john     30        kl
```

How can i do this?

I am using SQLite and javascript, angularjs

Thanks

Comment: Is this all the rows in the table? how can we know which age to connect to which name?

Comment: @sagi this is all the rows in the table. so all d details belong to d same user just tht it is in row format and i want to convert it to column format

Comment: Posted an answer, hope thats what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT max(case when description = 'name' then value end) as name,
       max(case when description = 'age' then value end) as age,
       max(case when description = 'location' then value end) as location
FROM YourTable(or query..)
```